# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estou fazendo um sistema de postagem usando PHP e Mysqli, mas aparece alguns erros que não estou conseguindo arrumar.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código PHP abaixo:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){

$autor = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['autor'])));
$titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['titulo'])));
$texto = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['texto'])));

$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO postagens (Titulo, Texto, Autor) VALUES ('$titulo', '$texto', '$autor')") or die(mysqli_error());

if ($sql){
    echo '<script>alert("Pergunta Enviada!");location.href=("");</script>';
}else{
    echo '<script>alert("Ocorreu um problema!");location.href=("");</script>';
}

}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        <label for="inputTitulo">Titulo</label>
        <input type="text" name="titulo" class="form-control" id="titulo"  required="" placeholder="titulo..">


    <label >Texto</label>
    <input type="text" name="texto" class="form-control"  required="" placeholder="escreva sua pergunta...">


    <label>Autor</label>
    <input type="text" name="autor" class="form-control"  required="" placeholder="Autor">



<button type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary" 
value="Publicar">Publicar!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Estilo procedural

string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

Answer (score 0):

Falta passar por parâmetro o objeto de conexão, por exemplo:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");

$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";

$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);
```

Ou no estilo orientado a objetos:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");

$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";

$city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($city);
```

Exemplos e explicações completas na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)